# Empty output from XCode crash symbolication

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, symbolicatecrash

I am not being able to extract the correct symbolication from a crash report. My app was rejected because it caused the following crash during review.

It is the first time I did symbolication. Am I doing something wrong? Where to go from here?!

Testing one of the threads that did not crash, just to make sure I had the symbolication properly setup.

```
MacBook-Pro:3 username$ atos -arch armv7 -o MyApp 0x000000010004895c 0x10003c000 + 51548
```

I get the following output which was useful.

```
0x000000010004895c
0x10003c000
+
ChatView.(updateMessages() -> ()).(closure #2).(closure #1) (in MyApp) (ChatView.swift:0)
```

But then when I tried to test each of the thread 5 memory locations...

```
MacBook-Pro:3 username$ atos -arch armv7 -o MyApp 0x0000000100093630 0x10003c000 + 357936
```

And I got the same for everyone, which is nothing...

```
0x0000000100093630
0x10003c000
+
0x00357936 (in MyApp)
```

Then I got the crash report symbolicated by:

```
MacBook-Pro:3 username$ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash -v MyApp.crash MyApp.app.dSYM/
```

The output made a bit more sense, but the MyApp 357936 is still returning nothing.

```
Thread 5 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.cloudkit.operation.callback
Thread 5 Crashed:
0   MyApp                       0x0000000100093630 0x10003c000 + 357936
1   CloudKit                        0x000000018a329650 __70-[CKDatabase(ConvenienceMethods) fetchRecordWithID:completionHandler:]_block_invoke + 324
2   CloudKit                        0x000000018a33e220 -[CKFetchRecordsOperation _finishOnCallbackQueueWithError:] + 556
3   CloudKit                        0x000000018a313a30 -[CKOperation _finishInternalOnCallbackQueueWithError:] + 516
4   CloudKit                        0x000000018a313818 -[CKOperation _handleCompletionCallback:] + 120
5   CloudKit                        0x000000018a3160ec __ck_dispatch_async_block_invoke + 36
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001813114bc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018131147c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018131d4c0 _dispatch_queue_drain + 864
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181314f80 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018131f390 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 728
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018131f0b0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181529470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181529020 start_wqthread + 4
```

**This is the crash report I got from Apple**

```
Version:             3 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-07-21 17:01:01.01 -0700
Launch Time:         2016-07-21 17:01:00.00 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 9.3.2 (13F69)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000100093630
Triggered by Thread:  5

Thread 5 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.cloudkit.operation.callback
Thread 5 Crashed:
0   MyApp                           0x0000000100093630 0x10003c000 + 357936
1   CloudKit                        0x000000018a329650 0x18a2d0000 + 366160
2   CloudKit                        0x000000018a33e220 0x18a2d0000 + 451104
3   CloudKit                        0x000000018a313a30 0x18a2d0000 + 277040
4   CloudKit                        0x000000018a313818 0x18a2d0000 + 276504
5   CloudKit                        0x000000018a3160ec 0x18a2d0000 + 286956
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001813114bc 0x181310000 + 5308
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018131147c 0x181310000 + 5244
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018131d4c0 0x181310000 + 54464
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181314f80 0x181310000 + 20352
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018131f390 0x181310000 + 62352
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018131f0b0 0x181310000 + 61616
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181529470 0x181528000 + 5232
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181529020 0x181528000 + 4128

Activity ID:             0x0000000000005793
Activity Name:           !client/fetch-records
Activity Image Path:     /System/Library/Frameworks/CloudKit.framework/CloudKit
Activity Image UUID:     5A0898B0-056F-3AA8-BB9A-6F5E84185C9A
Activity Offset:         0x0006e328
Activity Running Time:   0.876357 sec

Thread 5 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000100318be0   x2: 0x000000013e767950   x3: 0x000000013e767950
    x4: 0x000000000000000a   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x000000016e246948
    x8: 0x0000000000000001   x9: 0x000000016e2470e0  x10: 0x0000000000000000  x11: 0x000000170000001f
   x12: 0x000000013e599b30  x13: 0x0000000100365be8  x14: 0x0000000000010201  x15: 0x02325ecfaa4f70c7
   x16: 0x0000000180f45ef0  x17: 0x000000010032fe98  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x000000013e75d250
   x20: 0x0000000000000000  x21: 0x00000001000d8000  x22: 0x000000013e79bb90  x23: 0x000000013e7a3e81
   x24: 0x000000000000007c  x25: 0x4000000000000021  x26: 0x000000013e7a3e70  x27: 0x000000016e246b28
   x28: 0x000000013e767950  fp: 0x000000016e246be0   lr: 0x00000001000934bc
    sp: 0x000000016e2469f0   pc: 0x0000000100093630 cpsr: 0x60000000
```